# Play 2.3 - Changing to WebSocket.tryAccept from async

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new rather new to Scala so I think this might be a very small problem.

I'm currently trying to change the method `chat` from using the deprecated `WebSocket.async` to `WebSocket.tryAccept`. The application uses the sample chat found at [PlayFramework websocket-chat](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/samples/scala/websocket-chat/app/models/ChatRoom.scala)

I'm having trouble creating the complex `Future` type that the method requires.

This is the old method:

```
  def chat() = WebSocket.async[JsValue] {
    request =>
      ChatRoom.join("User: 1")
}
```

New method:

```
  def chat2() = WebSocket.tryAccept[JsValue] {
    request =>
      try {
        // ChatRoom.join returns (iteratee,enumerator)
        ChatRoom.join("User: 1").map(e => Right(e)) 
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          Left(Ok("Failed")) // Error here
  }
}
```

My error message:

`found   : Left[Result,Nothing]
required: Future[Either[Result,(Iteratee[JsValue, _], Enumerator[JsValue])]]`

I have no idea how I am supposed to create such a complex result for such a simple message.

Although `ChatRoom.join("User: 1").map(e => Right(e))` doesn't show any errors now, I'm unsure if this is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not in front of an IDE at the moment, so I can't answer fully, but the return type it's asking for isn't as complex as it seems. An "Either" is a "Left" or a "Right" in the same way that an "Option"  is a "Some" or a "None". So what it's asking for is a Future (which Websocket.async should also have required) that contains either a Left[Result] -- the fail-to-connect case, or a Right[(Iteratee, Enumerator)] -- the success case. Assuming that Chatroom.join returns a Future[(Iteratee, Enumerator)], the map operation is simply wrapping that in a "Right". The first thing I'd try is wrapping Left(Ok("Failed")) in a Future and see what happens.

Comment: Wrapping the Left return inside a `Future {... }` worked. I had previously tried wrapping the whole request inside a future, but that didn't work. Thanks.